# how do i create a method that generates a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jbutton

I have tried to create a method, that takes some parameters, to make a `JButton`. The button gets created, but it will not communicate with the `actionPerformed` method. Can anyone help me out here?

[this image contains how the button normally is made and the method to create a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIu70.png)

[this image shows the addButton method and the actionPerformed method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OnV5.png)

Comment: [Don't post pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your actionListener does not do anything aside from evaluating that `if`. But the condition of the `if` is never true.

Comment: java is call-by-value, so it's useless to pass `button19` as a parameter to overwrite that parameter in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course write a method that creates JButton for you:

```
public JButton createButton(String label, ActionListener listener, int x, int y) {
  JButton b = new JButton(label);
  name.addActionListener(listener);
  name.setBounds(x, y, 150, 50);
  return b;
}
```

and then use the method like this:

```
button19 = createButton("Toiletsager", this, 100, 100);
```

You can of course also specify one `ActionListener` for each button:

```
button20 = createButton("Toiletsager", e->System.out.println(e) , 100, 100);
```

Comment: Super, thx for that f1sh, it worked :)